# How to get a regular expression from URI, as in Laravel routing

Tags: php, regex

I want to get a regular expression for parsing REUQEST_URI from URI

example:

```
Route('/news/{author}/{id}/', function ($args){
    echo $args['id'];
    echo $args['author'];
});

function Route($uri, callable $func, array $args = null)
{
    code......
    $func($args);
}
```

As you understand, I reinvent the wheel. I just want to figure out how to get a regular expression in laravel from uri. I tried using regular expressions and using explode, but nothing good came out.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel router uses [symfony/routing](https://github.com/symfony/routing) internally, so maybe it's a good idea to look at its sources.

Especially at [Route.php](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/master/Route.php) file.

Refer to the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) if you want to know how symfony router works (similar to Laravel, but laravel is another abstraction layer on top of it).